# How to automatically start Tor on server?

Tags: linux, centos, tor

I have Tor installed on CentOS 6.6 x86_64 server that's also running cPanel.

The problem I'm having is that Tor doesn't appear to always be running.  Is there a way to set it up to always start when the server starts and to keep it running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better question for [Super User](http://superuser.com) but you want to start up the service on boot. To do this for Centos checkout the [chkconfig](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/chkconfig8.html) command where you should be able to apply `chkconfig --add tor` (or whatever the name of the tor service is called).

[Check this guy out](http://safesrv.net/have-services-start-at-boot-using-chkconfig-on-centos/) for a more in depth tutorial